# WMI permissions for changing local IP without elevated privileges

Tags: windows, permissions, nic, wmi, uac

I have implemented a tiny tool that allows one to change the IP settings of a selected Network Interface (NIC) by overwriting the values via the WMI. I've noticed that the tool can change the settings only if it has been started with "Run as administrator" option.

Which WMI permission should I grant the user so the changed values can be written without elevated privileges?

Answer (score 3):

Try making him or her a member of the local group: 'Network Configuration Operators'.

Comment: In this case under Windows 7 you can only set the static IP, but not to set to use the DHCP. Under Windows 10 you can't do the both of changes.

Comment: sorry for that, I only tested in 2012r2, I don't do workstation Windows.